# How to use play's form validation to check if the password matches

Tags: scala, playframework

My form looks like:

case class PasswordData(currentPassword: String, newPassword: String, verifyPassword: String)

```
val passwordForm = Form(
  mapping(
  )(PasswordData.apply)(PasswordData.unapply) verifying("Passwords do not match", fields => fields match {
    case data => (data.newPassword == data.verifyPassword)
})
)
```

My controller action follows the usual pattern:

```
passwordForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  error => {},
  form => {}
)
```

The problem I have now is I need to verify if the entered 'currentPassword' is the same as what is on the user's object.

```
userDao.getById(userId).password == form.currentPassword
```

But I can't do this because I am not sure how to pass int he userId to my form definition since it is dynamic.

i.e. I can't do it like:

```
"currentPassword" -> nonEmptyText.verifying(....)  // userId not in scope
```

**Update**

I am trying to display these errors also using (they don't currently display the error, I only see the ul tags).

```
 @if(form.hasGlobalErrors) {
    <ul>
        @form.errors.foreach { error =>
        <li>@error.message</li>
        }
    </ul>
    }
```

Comment: @m-z I think he is talking about `password` and `re-password`...

Comment: Yup...  he said that... Somehow missed it.

Comment: Well... the user_id should be provided somehow... be it a hidden filed in form... or in user session.

Comment: @m-z It isn't plain text, I tried to simplify the scenario as it doesn't really matter how I go about matching the password.  I have the userId in my session object, but I can't pass it into the form since that is a val

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is stopping you from making your `passwordForm` a def, where you can pass in a user model.

```
def passwordForm(user: User) = Form(
  mapping(
    "currentPassword" -> nonEmptyText.verifying("Incorrect password.", enteredPassword =>
       // some comparison with `enteredPassword` and the user
    ),
    ...
  )(PasswordData.apply)(PasswordData.unapply)
    .verifying("Passwords do not match", data => 
       data.newPassword == data.verifyPassword
    )
)


passwordForm(user).bindFromRequest.fold(
  error => ...,
  form => ...
)
```

Also, to print out the global errors in the view, they are accessed via `globalErrors`, and not the normal `errors` field. You should also use `map` instead of `foreach`. `foreach` returns `Unit`, which will not print anything to the view.

```
@if(form.hasGlobalErrors) {
    <ul>
        @form.globalErrors.map { error =>
          <li>@error.message</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when adding errors using verifying, do they go in global errors?  My errors do not display (see my updated question with my error display code please).

Comment: They are global errors if they are after the binding function. You can just as easily do this with `nonEmptyText` on the field, though. I've edited my answer to align more closely with your original form.

Comment: The 'passwords do not match' error doesn't display anywhere.  Any ideas why?